# Unable to login to Desktop, keeps returning to a terminal

Tags: 10.10, boot

Aloha, I'have been tried for several times updated software packages or drivers.

But always facing the problem. I can't log in to the dekstop, just at the terminal, it ask for username and login password.

Ater entered the username and password, still at terminal.. that's all..

Comment: What sort of video card do you have?  What drivers do you have installed?  Are they built against the current version of the kernel that you're booting?

Answer (score 1):

Log in on the console (the black screen you're referring to). Then, look in /var/log/Xorg.0.log and see if there's anything relevant there. If you don't find anything there, check out ~/.xsession-errors.

If you don't know how to look at files from the command line, try this:

```
~:$ less /var/log/Xorg.0.log
~:$ grep -v DEBUG < ~/.xsession-errors | less  # Filters out lines containing DEBUG
```

If you don't understand what you're seeing, post it here.

(PS: I know this isn't really much of an answer--it's really just troubleshooting--but since I'm not allowed to post comments, I have to frame this as an answer.)